# My register button is not working, it force close the apps after i pressed the button but there is no error appearing

Tags: java, android, button

My Button is not working, it force close the apps after i pressed on the button but there is no error appearing and it run usually. here is the stack trash of the apps.

```
        2019-11-11 13:09:50.306 1324-1324/? E/Icon:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
2019-11-11 13:09:50.408 2398-24306/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:09:50.453 19007-9921/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.mlite.sso.MessengerLoggedInUserProvider2019-11-11 13:09:50.751 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:50.754 1324-9945/? E/AudioFeatures: Application cannot support or Zenmode close2019-11-11 13:09:50.755 563-25368/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]2019-11-11 13:09:50.755 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5NormalFile false, bad magic:PK2019-11-11 13:09:50.755 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5MultimediaFile false, bad magic:2019-11-11 13:09:50.768 561-8675/? E/APEExtractor: getAPEInfo not ape 204842019-11-11 13:09:50.779 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:50.792 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:51.242 1013-9941/? E/VibratorService: motorModeEnableVibration---motor mode disable2019-11-11 13:09:51.312 571-7002/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf3835260:google.aac.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:09:51.313 571-7002/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf3835260:google.aac.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:09:51.351 428-4866/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo(), pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error =2019-11-11 13:09:53.569 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:53.570 1324-9993/? E/AudioFeatures: Application cannot support or Zenmode close2019-11-11 13:09:53.571 563-25368/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]2019-11-11 13:09:53.571 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5NormalFile false, bad magic:PK2019-11-11 13:09:53.571 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5MultimediaFile false, bad magic:2019-11-11 13:09:53.580 561-9816/? E/APEExtractor: getAPEInfo not ape 204822019-11-11 13:09:53.590 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:53.606 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:09:54.057 1013-9991/? E/VibratorService: motorModeEnableVibration---motor mode disable2019-11-11 13:09:54.125 571-4132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf3835260:google.aac.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:09:54.126 571-4132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf3835260:google.aac.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:09:55.544 10011-10011/? E/ANRManager: mPackageName = com.android.camera, Get anr service = android.app.anr.IANRManager$Stub$Proxy@34faa482019-11-11 13:10:00.591 19007-10035/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.mlite.sso.MessengerLoggedInUserProvider2019-11-11 13:10:00.883 2398-24306/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:00.883 2398-24306/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:00.950 1324-10062/? E/AudioFeatures: Application cannot support or Zenmode close2019-11-11 13:10:00.951 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:10:00.952 563-25368/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]2019-11-11 13:10:00.952 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5NormalFile false, bad magic:PK2019-11-11 13:10:00.953 563-25368/? E/Cta5File: Cta5File::isCta5MultimediaFile false, bad magic:2019-11-11 13:10:00.962 561-9816/? E/APEExtractor: getAPEInfo not ape 204822019-11-11 13:10:00.978 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:10:00.997 2398-2541/? E/VivoPush.PushInterfaceManager: (2398)onMessageReport messageId is not valid2019-11-11 13:10:01.443 1013-10060/? E/VibratorService: motorModeEnableVibration---motor mode disable2019-11-11 13:10:01.507 571-4132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf3834a80:google.aac.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:10:01.508 571-4132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf3834a80:google.aac.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-11-11 13:10:01.543 428-4866/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo(), pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error =2019-11-11 13:10:04.409 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:04.409 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:04.483 10080-10080/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.services2019-11-11 13:10:04.521 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AppInfoManager: (2398)uidAppInfoList is null2019-11-11 13:10:05.084 10128-10128/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.instagram.android2019-11-11 13:10:05.100 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AppInfoManager: (2398)uidAppInfoList is null2019-11-11 13:10:05.818 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:05.854 10128-10172/? E/AppStateReporter: Unpaired extra log file: /data/user/0/com.instagram.android/app_state_logs/com.instagram.android_b5870d8a-b196-1094-ff91-fd47e606f383.v2.txt_wrotedump2019-11-11 13:10:05.943 2398-9450/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2398)remove pid error : pids is null2019-11-11 13:10:10.950 10213-10213/? E/ANRManager: mPackageName = com.android.camera, Get anr service = android.app.anr.IANRManager$Stub$Proxy@34faa482019-11-11 13:10:15.179 567-684/? E/Netd: execIptablesRestore  commands *filter    -A fw_standby -m owner --uid-owner 99910194 -j DROP    COMMIT2019-11-11 13:10:15.794 1324-1324/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x7f07013f from pkg=com.android.mms.service    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07013f
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:264)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:912)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:855)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:324)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:277)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableAsUser(Icon.java:388)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:373)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:357)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:335)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:326)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(StatusBarIconView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:17419)
        at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:17138)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22399)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.vivo.systemui.statusbar.notification.VivoIconMerger.onMeasure(VivoIconMerger.java:24)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1148)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2597)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7182)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:677)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-11-11 13:10:15.795 1324-1324/? E/Icon:
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
2019-11-11 13:10:15.796 1324-1324/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x7f07013f from pkg=com.android.mms.service    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07013f
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:264)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:912)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:855)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:324)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:277)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableAsUser(Icon.java:388)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:373)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:357)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:335)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:326)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(StatusBarIconView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:17140)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22399)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.vivo.systemui.statusbar.notification.VivoIconMerger.onMeasure(VivoIconMerger.java:24)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1148)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2597)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7182)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:677)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557)
```

this is the full coding for main activity files.this coding is include with the database file and button code.

```
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
            private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
            private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
            private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
            private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
            private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
            private EditText etUsername;
            private EditText etPassword;
            private String username;
            private String password;
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            private String login_url = "http://192.168.0.199:loginapp/member/login.php";
            private SessionHandler session;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());

                if(session.isLoggedIn()){
                    loadDashboard();
                }
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsername);
                etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);

                // to delacre the button 
                Button btnLoginRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
                Button login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
                Button admin = findViewById(R.id.btnAdmin);

                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Retrieve the data entered in the edit texts
                        username = etUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                        if (validateInputs()) {
                            login();
                        }
                    }
                });

                //Launch Registration screen when Register Button is clicked
                btnLoginRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("Hello", "Register Button Clicked");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                admin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminLoginPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

it should go to the register page after i click on the register button, but it force closed.There is no error appearing.

Comment: what does `finish();` do ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: finish(); is to end the function of btn after clicked

Comment: There must be a problem in your `RegisterActivity.java` file. For example, setting click listener for a button without initializing it. It'd be helpful to trace the root cause for the problem as suggested by @MikeM.

Comment: Those logs aren't from your app. They're system errors. You can use the filters above the log window to restrict the output to your package/process.

Comment: but i do create a RegisterActivity.java file in it but all the name and declare is matched

Comment: where can i get to find the filter? @MikeM.

Comment: Right above the log window. It looks something like the screenshot shown here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running. Those dropdown boxes right above the text box.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are only seeing the selected application. try to open again Logcat then click the dropdown textbox seen on the upper right corner